# Writing a Givens Matrix as a Product of At Most Two Householder Transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a way of proving that any givens matrix is a product of at most two householder matrices?

Here is what I have tried so far:

I can see why this holds in two dimensions because any householder matrix can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\sin \theta & -\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}$$ for some angle $\theta$. This is just a reflection matrix, so I can apply at most two reflections. However, how can I generalize this to provide it for general $n \times n$ matrices?

Edit: my apologies. It should be at most two householder reflections.

Comment: @Ben Oof. Yes, absolutely. I don't know what I had in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, a $2 \times 2$ Givens matrix can be written as a product of Householder matrices:
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta} = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin \theta\\\sin \theta & - \cos \theta}\pmatrix{\cos 2\theta & \sin 2\theta\\\sin 2\theta & - \cos 2\theta}.
$$
This translates directly into a more general decomposition: the Givens rotation $G(i,j,\theta)$ (in the notation of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation)) can be written as follows: let $H(i,j,\theta)$ denote the matrix whose non-zero entries are given by $h_{ii} = \cos \theta$, $h_{jj} = - \cos\theta$, $h_{ij} = h_{ji} = \sin \theta$. Then
$$
G(i,j,\theta) = H(i,j,\theta)H(i,j,2 \theta).
$$
Or, as the comment notes,
$$
G(i,j,\theta) = H(i,j,\theta)H(i,j,0)
$$
works just as well.

Comment: You could also replace the last factor by $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}=I-2e_2e_2^T=H(.,.;0)$ for a more direct sign flip.

Comment: @Lutz I'm not sure why I didn't think of that